Yang-Mills Path integral quantization
I am reading N. Beisert's lecture note QFT II Section 4.3.
There, the author explains how to give a definition to
$$
  Z[J] = \int \mathcal{D} A \exp (i S_{\text{YM}}[A,J])
$$
They use the following delta functional identity to separate the divergence factor due to overcounting gauge equivalent sections. Here, $A$ is fixed and
$$A(U) = U A U^{-1} + i U \partial U^{-1}.\tag{4.66}$$
$$
  1 = \int \mathcal{D} U \Delta(G[A(U), \Omega]) \det_{a,b,x,y} \left(\frac{\delta G[A(U), \Omega]^a(x)}{\delta \alpha^b(y)}\right)
\tag{4.64}$$
where $$G[A, \Omega] = \partial^{\mu} A_{\mu} - \Omega\tag{4.63}$$ is the term to implement gauge fixing.
The determinant term is the Jacobian.
I understand $\alpha$ is Lie algebra valued corresponding to $U$,
but shouldn't the path integral be over $\mathcal{D} \alpha$?
The author also explains the analogous argument for the abelian $U(1)$ theory in the preceding Section 4.2, which I understand. There, the path integral is over $\mathcal{D} \alpha$.

Shouldn't the determinant be evaluated at $\alpha = 0$? Then the integratation over $U$ seems more clear no?

I think the gauge transformation $U$ itself is not infinitesimal, only $\delta U$ is. So I don't see why it should be evaluated at $\alpha = 0$. My understanding is, when calculating determinant, $G(A(U + \delta U)) - G(A(U)) = G(A(1 + i \delta \alpha)U) - G(A(U))$ is the numerator.

That determinant fixes the normalization.  Since the integrand vanishes away from $U=1$ or $\alpha =0$, it's OK to mess up the normalization.

TL;DR: At one point in the Faddeev-Popov trick, one needs the translation invariant of the Haar measure of the Lie group $G$.

On one hand, for an abelian group $G=U(1)$, this is implemented by integrating over the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{u}(1)$, cf. eqs. (4.39) & (4.42-43) in Section 4.2.

On the other hand, integrating over a non-abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ [instead of the Haar measure for the non-abelian Lie group $G$] would for starters require an extra non-trivial Jacobian factor.


